# Can't receive updates from ValueNotifier when used from MethodCallHandler

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-channel

I have a simple Widget with a `ValueListenableBuilder` that listens to a `ValueNotifier`.

The build function of the `ValueListenablebuilder` is never triggered when updating the value of the `ValueNotifier` from a native method call (using `setMethodCallHandler`).

Instead, if I use `valueNotifier.listen(() {})`, I'm able to receive new values even in the build function. The native code, in fact, emits a new String each second.

This is the minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```dart
class Main extends StatelessWidget {

  Main({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    platform.invokeMethod("startNativeMethod");
    platform.setMethodCallHandler(handleNativeMethod);

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
      // this WORKS and updates the Text!
      resourceNotifier.value = "test";
    });

    resourceNotifier.addListener(() {
      // this ALWAYS works (prints "test" and then native updates each second)
      print(resourceNotifier.value);
    });

    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: resourceNotifier,
        builder: (context, String value, child) {
          // this is triggered only with "test"
          // (when updated from Future.delayed)
          return Container(child: Text(value ?? "Empty")); 
        });
  }


  ValueNotifier<String> resourceNotifier = ValueNotifier(null);
  MethodChannel platform = const MethodChannel("com.example.example");

  Future<dynamic> handleNativeMethod(MethodCall call) async {
    // this NEVER updates the Text() widget. Always triggers the listener instead.
    resourceNotifier.value = "hello from native";
  }
}
```

This goes also beyond ValueNotifiers. I've also tried moving to a Stateful Widget and setting state from handleNativeMethod. Even `setState` doesn't work from there.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I still have `I/flutter (26653): hello from native #8`, `I/flutter (26653): handleNativeMethod 9` ecc... So `handleNativeMethod` prints the global variable correctly. The listener also prints the global variable correctly. Still, the build widget is not triggered at each update.